# Exclude files from gradle transitive dependency

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, jackson

It's all in the question i'm trying to exclude a file

In this case le lib is **commons-codec-1.8**, the file is LICENSE which is already added in **jackson-core-2.3.2**

I found this method :

```
compile('com.cognitect:transit-java:0.8.269'){
    exclude files: ''
}
```

But I don't know how to use it ?

EDIT1:

I get this kind of error when trying to execute my app

```
Duplicate files during packaging of APK .../basic/build/apk/basic-debug-unaligned.apk
Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt File 1: /home/scijoker/AndroidStudioProjects/ProgProject/Prog/libs/httpclient-4.1.1.jar File 2: /home/scijoker/AndroidStudioProjects/ProgProject/Prog/libs/httpclient-4.1.1.jar
```

And this kind also :

```
Path in archive: about.html
Origin 1: ...filestore/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlet/8.1.8.v20121106/jar/285ea47746e9ab988a8291ea9fd6545b537e0ce9/jetty-servlet-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
Origin 2: ...filestore/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client/8.1.8.v20121106/jar/f194a5a07ada9dab48e226c4e8152d120ce1e76f/jetty-client-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
```

Issue tracker : 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61573

Comment: Your question does not makes sense. Every jar is going to have some files with the same name. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: updated my question, yes you are right except here this should not happen